# Javascript inheritence extend method tips

Tags: javascript

I am working on an extend method to create subtypes of objects and functions in JavaScript. I am struggling a little understanding exactly how these two lines are different:

- f.prototype = p;
- f.prototype = new p();

Could I get an explanation of what is actually taking place behind the scenes?

My understanding is when I pass in an object, if I use 'new p();' the constructor is called which may not exist.  Is this correct?  Would there be a way to consolidate any of this code?

```
    function extend(p) {
        if (p == null) throw TypeError(); 

        var f = function() {}, 
            t = typeof p;

        if( t === 'object' ) {
            f.prototype = p;

            f.prototype.constructor = f;
            return new f();

        } else if( t === 'function' ) {
            f.prototype = new p(); 

            f.prototype.constructor = f;
            return f; 
        } else {
            throw TypeError();
        }
    }       

    // ==========================
    var Person = {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    };
    console.log( 'Person: ', Person );

    var Employee = extend( Person );
    Employee.prototype = {
        employeeID: 0
    }

    console.log( 'Employee: ', Employee );

    var Manager = extend( Employee );
    Manager.prototype.fireEveryone = function() {
        alert( 'Everyone is fired!!!!' );
    }
    console.log( 'Manager: ', Manager );
```

Thanks

Comment: I've just gotten past this issue [This might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13072338/1257652)

Answer (score 0):

While I too will be eagerly awaiting to see the answers posted in reply to this question, I would recommend you to look at the new inheritance/OOP mechanism introduced in ECMAScript 5, which I think works more cohesively as far as JavaScript is concerned.

More here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Golmaal, I actually was taking a look at these before posting ...then saw this: [link](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)

I am using IE8 which the ECMAScript 5 isn't supported.